# Set affinity of c++ std::thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11, std

I am trying to make precise time measurements in Windows when UDP datagrams arrive. Reading documentation from Microsoft I have decided to use QueryPerformanceCounter. In the same documentation it suggests that you set the affinity and performance of the timing thread. I am using Boost and c++ 11 to implement my async UDP server:

```
void receiveEvent()
{
  listening_socket.async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(event_buffer, max_length), signaling_endpoint,
    [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_recvd)
    {
      if (!ec && bytes_recvd > 0)
      {
        LARGE_INTEGER prectime;
        ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&prectime);
        std::cout << prectime.QuadPart << std::endl;
      } else if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
        std::cout << "socket canceled" << std::endl;
        return;
      }
      receiveEvent();
    });
}

listening_socket(io, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), port));
receiveEvent();
async_thread = std::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
// TODO set thread affinity using SetProcessAffinityMask
// TODO set thread priority using SetPriorityClass
```

How do I use `std::thread async_thread` with `SetProcessAffinityMask` and `SetPriorityClass`?

Comment: `SetProcessAffinityMask` and `SetPriorityClass` apply to the whole process, not just one thread. You might be thinking of `SetThreadAffinityMask` and `SetThreadPriority`.

Comment: MSVC's implementation of `std::thread::native_handle()` returns a `HANDLE` to the thread. You can pass it to those functions. The problem however is that there's no way to tell `std::thread` to create a thread  suspended (as you would with `CreateThread(CREATE_SUSPENDED)`), so you could set those options before it gets to actually run.

Comment: There's no point in doing this, the return value of QPC is not affected by what core the code runs on.